# Native "with" query works in the SQL console but return no data as native query in hibernate (an inner join fails)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jhipster, h2

tl;dr I have a long native query in Hibernate, that is split in multiple queries (with table as ...). This Query use inner joins that not work in hibernate (empty result), but work excellent in the SQL Console. Also if I copy/paste the query from the hibernate logs into the console.

```
with params as (select ca.id as calculation_id, chart_id, range_size, range_size * interval '1' minute as size
                from calculation ca
                         inner join chart c on c.id = ca.chart_id
                         inner join time_range tr on tr.id = c.time_range_id
                where ca.id = :calculationid),
     tuple_diff as (select t.calculation_id,
                           t.id,
                           t.ohlc_id,
                           t.time, t.time - lag(t.time, 1) over (order by t.time) as diff
                     from tuple t inner join params p
                       on t.calculation_id = p.calculation_id),
     ohlc_diff as (select o.chart_id,
                          o.id,
                          o.time,
                          o.time - lag(o.time, 1) over (order by o.time) as diff
                   from ohlc o inner join params p on o.chart_id = p.chart_id),
     tuple_filtered as (select id, ohlc_id, time, diff, p.size, p.range_size
                         from tuple_diff t
                                  inner join params p on chart_id = p.chart_id
                         where diff <> p.size),
     ohlc_filtered as (select o.chart_id, o.id as ohlc_id, time
                       from ohlc_diff o
                                inner join params p on o.chart_id = p.chart_id
                       where o.diff <> p.size)
select t.time as time, t.range_size as size
from tuple_filtered t
         left join ohlc_filtered o on t.time = o.time
where o.ohlc_id is null
order by t.time;
```

The long version, I have a microservice, generated with jhipster and the project runs productive with PostgreSQL and in development mode with a H2 Database. I have ohlc stockexchange time series and calculate calculations with an other microservice and store the computation in a tuple table. Sometimes I have holes in the timeline and want to recalculate them. I need to get the time difference to the last calculation. This is not an easy SQL Query, because you need to access the previous row like in Excel. I use the [lag function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to solve this problem. But the lag function is not the reason.

[image: Datastructure in Jhipster JDL Studio]

I generate a test project with an [integration test](https://github.com/joe-bookwood/querybug/blob/main/src/test/java/de/bitc/se/service/CalculationServiceIT.java#L173) to analyze the problem. The Junit Test is `de.bitc.se.service.CalculationServiceIT` and run with a [Postgresql Testcontainer](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/). The test also fill the SQL tables with testdata. I start to split the query in small parts.

```
with params as (select ca.id as ca_id, 
                       chart_id, range_size, 
                       range_size * interval '1' minute as size
                from calculation ca
                         inner join chart c on c.id = ca.chart_id
                         inner join time_range tr on tr.id = c.time_range_id
                where ca.id = :calculationid)
select ca_id, chart_id, range_size
from params
order by ca_id;
```

This part works like the console.

```
with tuple_diff as (select t.calculation_id,
                           t.id,
                           t.ohlc_id,
                           t.time,
                           t.time - lag(t.time, 1) over (order by t.time) as diff
                    from tuple t
                    where calculation_id = :calculationid)
select calculation_id, time
from tuple_diff
order by calculation_id;
```

The second query too, but when I try to join the query's, I got an empty result:

```
with params as (select ca.id as ca_id,
                       chart_id,
                       range_size, range_size * interval '1' minute as size
                from calculation ca
                         inner join chart c on c.id = ca.chart_id
                         inner join time_range tr on tr.id = c.time_range_id
                where ca.id = :calculationid),
     tuple_diff as (select t.calculation_id,
                           t.id,
                           t.ohlc_id,
                           t.time,
                           t.time - lag(t.time, 1) over (order by t.time) as diff
                    from tuple t
                             inner join params p on p.ca_id = t.calculation_id
                    where calculation_id = ca_id)
select calculation_id
from tuple_diff
order by calculation_id;
```

When I try to join the `param` query (one result) with the `tuple` table I got no result. In the SQL console I got a result of multiple lines. I used the EntityManager to exclude Spring Data code in the splitted queries in the integration test.

I have no idea why I got no result. Is it a bug in Hibernate or a mistake?

Comment: H2 or Postgres? Please do not add tags for databases not involved

Comment: My productive database is postgresql, in development mode, I use H2. But postgresql and H2 works excellent when I execute the query in the SQL console. So I think it is a hibernate problem. I taged as postgresql to avoid missunderstandings with the window functions and the **with** syntax.

Comment: I opened a hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15673